# NuGet pack Ignoring -Prop Arguments When -Build Specified

Tags: build-automation, release, nuget

I am trying to deploy to NuGet using a script. I have the following command for doing the actual deployment:

```
nuget pack MyProjection.csproj -Build -Properties Configuration=Release
```

Based the examples provided on NuGet's website, this is the correct command line. I noticed that some examples say `-Prop` rather than `-Properties`, but I don't think it matters.

However, NuGet outputs:

```
Attempting to build package from 'MyProject.csproj'.
Building project for target framework '.NETFramework,Version=v4.0'.
Packing files from 'C:\Users\...\MyProjection\bin\Debug'.
Using 'MyProject.nuspec' for metadata.
Successfully created package 'C:\Users\...\MyProject\MyProject.2.2.0.0.nupkg'.
```

Notice that it is packaging files in the `Debug` folder instead of the `Release` folder!

If I remove the `-Build` setting, it grabs the files from the `Release` like it's supposed to. The first question is: have I been publishing debug versions of my project? The second question is: how do I use these two command arguments together?

If I have to, I'll build the project using MSBuild.

Answer (score 4):

When packing a project, nuget will use the current project settings, ignoring the Configuration option passed from the command line. The same would go for the basepath argument, for instance.

If you change the default configuration to release, nuget will build your package using the release bits. Look for the following in your .csproj:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
```

And change it to:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Release</Configuration>
```

Comment: I just switched over to using MSBuild. I am running MSTest as part of my deployment phase anyway, so what's one more .exe dependency?

Comment: True. Just be aware that Nuget will **still** look for bin\debug if you pack a csproj.  I'm also building with msbuild then packing with nuget, but I needed to change the project's default build configuration to ensure it packs the release bits.